# Javascript regex for matching valid characters without repetition of a particular character

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let rx = /(\/MxML\/[a-z0-9\[\]@/]*)/gi;
let s =
    'If (/MxML/trades[1]/value== 1 then /MxML/trades[type=2]/value must be /MxML/stream/pre/reference@href';

let m;
let res = [];

while ((m = rx.exec(s))) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

1. Pattern should start with /MxML/
2. Keep including acceptable characters [a-z0-9[]@/]
3. A single `=` is ok. But `==` or `===` are not ok.

Desired output

```
[
    '/MxML/trades[1]/value',
    '/MxML/trades[type=2]/value',
    '/MxML/stream/pre/reference@href',
];
```

My current (incorrect) output

```
[
    '/MxML/trades[1]/value',
    '/MxML/trades[type',
    '/MxML/stream/pre/reference@href',
];
```

I can think of a lookaround, but can't figure out how to use it here.
`(?<!\=)\=(?!\=)`

I've been going through several other examples on Stackoverflow, but they are about avoiding all character repetition and not about avoiding a particular character(=) repetition in conjunction with other valid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex which should be compatible in all browsers:

```js
/(\/MxML\/(?:[a-z0-9\[\]@/]|=(?!=))*)/gi
```

- `/(\/MxML\/` - your regex
- `(?:` - start non-capture group; we need this to implement an "or" operator and not mess up your use of `m[1]`

  - `[a-z0-9\[\]@/]` - your regex of whitelisted chars; notice the asterisk was removed
  - `|` - or
  - `=(?!=)` - allow for an equal sign not followed by an equal sign
- `)*` - close non-capturing group and capture between zero and infinity instances of what's inside
- `)/gi` - your regex

```js
let rx = /(\/MxML\/(?:[a-z0-9\[\]@/]|=(?!=))*)/gi;
let s =
    'If (/MxML/trades[1]/value== 1 then /MxML/trades[type=2]/value must be /MxML/stream/pre/reference@href';

let m;
let res = [];

while ((m = rx.exec(s))) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a line of explanation please, including what is `:` for.

Comment: @KayaToast It's a non-capturing group. I didn't want to mess up your use of `m[1]`

Comment: @KayaToast I edited my answer to explain the regex a bit more